# How can i implement jwt to my rest api? without using spring security

Tags: java, api, jwt

I am trying to implement security to my rest api with jwt as authentication method, in my API I am using spring boot , the new version of spring seems to have problems with spring security , could jwt be implemented without using spring security?

I would like to implement jwt without the need to use spring security to my rest order api, which handles 3 roles (admin, user and client)